# Update a value from a delegate method on GUI thread without calling the event from the GUI

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, trading

I am an example C# program I am writing from using the template from http://www.ctsfutures.com/wiki/T4%20API%2040.MainPage.ashx

Here is some of the code:

declare moAccounts which is from their API

```
internal AccountList moAccounts;
```

create Delegate

```
private delegate void OnPositionUpdateDelegate(T4.API.Position poPosition);
```

Inside of Init() it registers

```
moAccounts.PositionUpdate += new T4.API.AccountList.PositionUpdateEventHandler(moAccounts_PositionUpdate);
```

I believe this gets called when a trade is entered and Position is updated.  Position would be like you are in 100 shares of Google, etc.. so it would be just 100.

```
 //' Event that is raised when positions for accounts have changed.
    private void moAccounts_PositionUpdate(AccountList.PositionUpdateList poPositions)
    {

        // Display the position details.

        {

            foreach (AccountList.PositionUpdateList.PositionUpdate oUpdate in poPositions)
            {
                // If the position is for the current account
                // then update the value.

                if (object.ReferenceEquals(oUpdate.Account, moAccount))
                {
                    // Invoke the update.
                    // This places process on GUI thread.
                    // Must use a delegate to pass arguments.
                    if (this.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        this.BeginInvoke(new OnPositionUpdateDelegate(OnPositionUpdate), new object[] { oUpdate.Position });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OnPositionUpdate(oUpdate.Position);
                    }

                    break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Then this gets called

```
        private void OnPositionUpdate(T4.API.Position poPosition)
    {

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(poPosition.Market, moMarket))
        {

            // Display the position details.
            DisplayPosition(poPosition.Market, 1);
        }

    }
```

Then this gets called which updates the TextBox that holds the number of positions

```
private void DisplayAccount(Account poAccount)
            {

                if ((moAccount != null))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        // Lock the host while we retrive details.
                        moHost.EnterLock("DisplayAccount");

                        // Display the current account balance.
                        txtCash.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", moAccount.AvailableCash);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Trace the error.
                        Trace.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString());

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // Unlock the host object.
                        moHost.ExitLock("DisplayAccount");

                    }

                }

            }


            private void DisplayPosition(Market poMarket, int piID)
            {
                string strNet = "";
                string strBuys = "";
                string strSells = "";

                bool blnLocked = false;

                try
                {

                    if ((poMarket != null) && (moAccount != null))
                    {
                        // Lock the host while we retrive details.
                        moHost.EnterLock("DisplayPositions");

                        // Update the locked flag.
                        blnLocked = true;


                        // Temporary position object used for referencing the account's positions.
                        Position oPosition = default(Position);

                        // Display positions for current account and market1.

                        // Reference the market's positions.
                        oPosition = moAccount.Positions[poMarket.MarketID];

                        Trace.WriteLine("Inside of DisplayPosition: " + oPosition.ToString());

                        if ((oPosition != null))
                        {
                            // Reference the net position.
                            strNet = oPosition.Net.ToString();
                            strBuys = oPosition.Buys.ToString();
                            strSells = oPosition.Sells.ToString();

                            // this part is what I added
                           // this is an int value
                            _positionQuantity = oPosition.Net;

                        }

                        switch (piID)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                // Display the net position.
                                txtNetPosition.Text = strNet;
                                break;
                        }

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Trace the error.
                    Trace.WriteLine("Error " + ex.ToString());

                }
                finally
                {
                    // Unlock the host object.
                    if (blnLocked)
                        moHost.ExitLock("DisplayPositions");

                }

            }
```

I notice if I call _positionQuantity from Trace.WriteLine, it does not update.  However, when I called it from MessageBox.Show(_positionQuantitiy), then it updates.

My problem is I have internal calculations that have to be done without GUI items.  How can I update _positionQuantity without having to call it from a GUI event type thing and just have it update when I need it

thanks
Spencer

Answer (score 0):

Updates to Windows Forms controls must be made on the same thread that created them. (This is, they have *thread affinity*.) To execute a delegate on the UI thread, call the `Invoke` method of the form, like this:

```
myForm.Invoke(() => {
                        doThis(someControl);
                        doThat(anotherControl);
                        doTheOther(anotherControl, 42);
                    });
```

The stuff in the curly braces is called an *anonymous method*. Single-line ones work too, of course:

```
myForm.Invoke(() => {someControl.Text = "Threads!";});
```

If you want to update the form's visual state immediately, you can use `theForm.Refresh();`.